# iOS - Wierd out of bound exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a pickerView with some strings in it `(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7)` and in the other component `(0,15,30,45)`

everything is working fine except, when i choose something from component 1, above 3. it gives me an out of bounds exception.

in `viewDidLoad` i declare it and fill it.

```
hoursArray = @[@"0",@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5",@"6",@"7"];
```

i do not touch it at all, only for nslogs.
in the pickers didSelectRow, i can `NSlog([hoursarray objectAtindex:7)` and it writes 7.

but if i pick above 3 in the picker, it gives me:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason:
>   '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]

the following code is a NSLOG to print array index 4, its working.
but in the picker index 4 is out of bounds, and it IS the same array

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component{

NSLog(@"hours array index 4:%@",[hoursArray objectAtIndex:7]);


NSString *selectedHours = @"0";
NSString *selectedQuarters = @"0";

//get picker values
if(component==0) {
    selectedHours = [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
    selectedQuarters = [quarterArray objectAtIndex:row];
}else {
    selectedHours = [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
    selectedQuarters = [quarterArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
//create formatted date
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@" dd/MM"];
NSString *displayDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];

NSString *lblString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Tryk for at tilføje %@ time(r) & %@ minutter til d. %@ ",selectedHours,selectedQuarters,displayDate];

[btnRegistrer setTitle:lblString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

}

Comment: You should also show some code !

Comment: It seems to me that you are using the (0, 15, 30, 45) in the picker.

Comment: I dont know what to show really, it's really simple. i make an array, fill it, tries to get the value picked in the picker, and it gives a wierd exception.

Comment: Maybe you inverted the two components of the pickerView...the exception talks about an array of 4 elements, that could be the one you name "the other component" which have just 4 elements :-)

Comment: Show pickerView delegate methods.

Comment: You are probably using wrong array for wrong picker. What is if(component==0) ?

Comment: I have checked for that 1000 times, im 99,9% sure that i'm not xD

Comment: Have a look at numberOfRowsInComponent. It's not the number of items in the array that is the problem, it's the number of items in the picker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the same code in both statements of the if!!
It should be:

```
if(component==0) {
    selectedHours = [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
}else {
    selectedQuarters = [quarterArray objectAtIndex:row];
}
```

EDIT: I answered before seeing your last edit with the complete delegate method, moreover you have to change a bit the logic because, if the user changes both hours and quarters, you'll have TWO subsequent delegate calls, and you'll have to adjust `selectedHours` and `selectedQuarters`.
You'd better move these two variables inside a @property to accomplish this

Comment: Yes, you beat me to it!  Hopefully this is just a case of looking at the same code for too long

Comment: That still doesn't answer why my hoursArray is outofbound above index 3

Comment: The out of bound array is not hoursArray! It's quarter array!!! Follow me: the user changes the first column (hours) selecting 7, the if goes through the first option (component == 0), then you do objectAtIndex:7 on hoursArray (correct) AND on quarterArray (wrong, exception is thrown)

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to write clear code .. It may help you..

```
-(void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:  (NSInteger)component{

  NSLog(@"hours array index 4:%@",[hoursArray objectAtIndex:7]);

  //get picker values
 if(component==0) {
    self.selectedHours = [hoursArray objectAtIndex:row];
   }else if(component==1){
    self.selectedQuarters = [quarterArray objectAtIndex:row];
   }

  [self showButtonTitle];
}
-(void)showButtonTitle
{
   //create formatted date
  NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
  [formatter setDateFormat:@" dd/MM"];
  NSString *displayDate = [formatter stringFromDate:[datePicker date]];

  NSString *lblString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Tryk for at tilføje %@ time(r) &     %@ minutter til d. %@     ",self.selectedHours,self.selectedQuarters,displayDate];

   [btnRegistrer setTitle:lblString forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```